# How many bits is a WORD and is that constant over different architectures?

Tags: data-structures, assembly, naming, cpu-architecture

Is a machine *WORD* always the same or does it depend on the machine architecture?
And is the meaning of the word *WORD* context sensitive or generally applicable?

Comment: In winapi speak, word is still fixed to 16-bit Windows and thus 16-bit, even on architectures with a large machine size. So in general in Windows HLL programs, word is 16-bit, so it is definitely context sensitive. As Guffa already says, the same 16-bittisms still exist in x86 assembler.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The machine word size depends on the architecture, but also how the operating system is running the application.

In Windows x64 for example an application can be run either as a 64 bit application (having a 64 bit mahine word), or as a 32 bit application (having a 32 bit machine word). So the size of a machine word can differ even on the same machine.

The term `WORD` has different meaning depending on how it's used. It can either mean a machine word, or a type with a specific size. In x86 assembly language `WORD`, `DOUBLEWORD` (`DWORD`) and `QUADWORD` (`QWORD`) are used for 2, 4 and 8 byte sizes, regardless of the machine word size.

Answer (score 15):

A word is typically the "native" data size of the CPU. That is, on a 16-bit CPU, a word is 16 bits, on a 32-bit CPU, it's 32 and so on.

And the exception, of course, is x86, where a word is 16 bit wide (because x86 was originally a 16-bit CPU), a DWORD is 32-bit (because it became a 32-bit CPU), and a QWORD is 64-bit (because it now has 64-bit extensions bolted on)

Comment: You mean I can't use QWORD on 32-bit machine at all?

Comment: @selurvedu Old comment, but for people who may come across this in the future; you likely can. Intel processors tend to have 64-bit MMX registers which enable you to use QWORDs and you can always read/write 64-bits of data to/from memory (keeping endianness in mind).

Comment: With regard to @SomeGuy's point about endianness, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7865511/2636454) is helpful in understanding that.

Answer (score 3):

It depends upon the machine architecture. [This](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Unix-and-Internet-Fundamentals-HOWTO/core-formats.html) document explains some basics about this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Ok, let me be a bit clearer. Assuming we are talking about words of memory, there are two broad definitions.

First, a word is often the natural size of a single item that can be accessed atomically in the hardware. That is very much a platform dependent size, but is usually 16, 32, or 64 bits, but other sizes have been found in the wild.

Second, it is often used to specifically mean a 16-bit value. In that context, you will see DWORD used to mean a 32-bit value. This usage is common on x86 platforms, especially Windows, but was used on DEC PDP-11 and VAX, and Motorola 68000 descendants as well.

Telling which is the intended usage depends on context...

Answer (score 2):

`WORD` is a [Windows specific 16-bit integer type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383751(VS.85).aspx), and is hardware independent.

If you mean a machine word, then there's no need to shout.

Answer (score 1):

16 bits (2 bytes) to a word is universal for x86.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that a WORD is the amount of bits that can be shoved into the CPU with one action (on a particular machine), so in a 8bit-architecture it is 8 bits and on a modern 64-bit architecture it is 64 bits.

Comment: In 8-bit land, we would never have said word when we meant byte. A common definition of word has been simply "two bytes", even on systems with 9-bit bytes and 18-bit words. The PDP-10 comes to mind there...

Answer (score 1):

All you youngsters yappin' on about 32 bit thiss and 64 bit that: you know, there were and are other machine architectures than the x86 family. A PDP-11 had 40-bit words, f'rinstance.

But the simplest answer is just to search [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computing)).

Comment: Someone missing a sense of humour, or have to get rid of reputation points? Have fun, either way.

Comment: The PDP-11 had 16-bit words. The PDP-10 (DEcSystem-10) had 36-bit words. I'm not aware of a DEC architecture with 40-bit words, but they had so many!

Comment: PDP-11's (at least those running RT-11, but I think it was used in other DEC OSs also) did use a strange character set known as Rad50 that allowed a 6.3 file name to fit in three words, with three characters per word. DEC liked quirky data packing ;-) (I have a running PDP-11 in my office.)

Answer (score 1):

A "word" in small letters depends on the architecture.

A "WORD" in capital letters, as defined in Windows SDK, is 16 bits.

Similarly:
"DWORD" - (double word) 32 bits.
"QWORD" ...             64 bits.