# QWORD Storing / implementing using 32-bit REGs.?

Tags: assembly, x86

Given that variable I is defined as Qword, the equation I = 2*I can be implemented using the following minimal instructions:

the solution :

```
MOV EAX, DWORD PTR I
ADD DWORD PTR I, EAX
```

what i dont get ...

```
MOV EAX, DWORD PTR I+4
ADC DWORD PTR I+4, EAX
```

Answer (score 4):

X86 is a [little endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) architecture. This means that numbers are stored with the least significant bytes first.

As an example `0x1234` is stored in memory with the `0x34` byte first followed by `0x12`. The wikipedia article has much more, but I'll quickly summarize:

```
Memory location:       X      X+1
                    +------+------+
Content (byte)      | 0x34 | 0x12 |
                    +------+------+
```

Is how the word `0x1234` is stored in memory. So if you access the least significant byte at memory location X, the most significant byte is stored at X + 1. Let's look at a DWORD (0x12345678):

```
Memory location:       Y      Y+1    Y+2    Y+3
                    +------+------+------+------+
Content (byte)      | 0x78 | 0x56 | 0x34 | 0x12 |
                    +------+------+------+------+
```

Within this you can access the individual bytes (as in the above example) OR you can access a word at memory location Y (0x5678) AND Y + 2 (0x1234). Similarly for a QWORD (0x0001020304050607):

```
Memory location:       Z      Z+1    Z+2    Z+3    Z+4    Z+5    Z+6    Z+7
                    +------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
Content (byte)      | 0x07 | 0x06 | 0x05 | 0x04 | 0x03 | 0x02 | 0x01 | 0x00 |
                    +------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

So you can think of the QWORD as consisting of 2 DWORDS, 4 words or 8 bytes. You can see that the second (most significant) dword  is stored at Z+4. You can also do you arithmetic on either of these representations as long as you remember that the least significant bytes/word/dwords are stored first and [carry/borrow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry_flag) appropriately.

So:

```
    MOV EAX, DWORD PTR I
    ADD DWORD PTR I, EAX
```

Adds the lower 4 bytes (a DWORD) to itself (doubling it) and in the process sets (if applicable) the carry flag, which is the added to the upper part (along with it also being doubled):

```
    MOV EAX, DWORD PTR I+4
    ADC DWORD PTR I+4, EAX
```

If it's the carry part you're having trouble grasping, consider this smaller example of adding `0x00FF` and `0x1001` together byte by byte:

```
    MOV AX, 0x00FF ; AL=0xFF AH=0x00
    MOV BX, 0x1001 ; BL=0x01 AH=0x10

    ADD AL, BL     ; Add lower parts, the result is 0x100 which 
                   ; doesn't fit in 8 bits, i.e. AL=0x00 now and
                   ; the carry flag is set

    ADC AH, BH     ; Add the most significant bytes together and 
                   ; include the carry flag. That is 0x00 + 0x10 + 1 = 0x11

    ; Final result AX = 0x1100
```

Comment: the second part please ... i dont get the second part :( !!

Comment: The `I+4` part? That's addressing the most significant dword part of the qword. I can elaborate if that's where the confusion lies.

Comment: why whould i add the carry flag to my answer and why whould i add 4 to I in the Q?

Comment: yah exactly addressing the upper half of the Qword

Comment: Updated and added some relevant links to wikipedia articles. They probably explain it better than I can.

Answer (score 1):

In x86 parlance, a WORD is 16 bits, a DWORD 32 bits, and a QWORD 64 bits. So, a QWORD consists of 2 DWORDS, one of them we will refer to as the LOW DWORD (this one goes to a lower memory address, since the x86 is little endian), and the other we will refer as the HIGH DWORD.

```
MOV EAX, DWORD PTR I
ADD DWORD PTR I, EAX
```

The above adds the LOW DWORD to itself.

```
MOV EAX, DWORD PTR I+4
ADC DWORD PTR I+4, EAX
```

The above adds the HIGH DWORD to itself, taking into account any leftover carry from the previous addition (that of the LOW DWORD to itself).