# How can you tell the size of a register in x86?

Tags: assembly, x86

How would you know how to fill in the underscore in the following assembly code:

```
mov_ %eax, (%rsp)
```

It's either "b" for byte, "w" for word, "l" for double word, or "q" for quad.  The syntax of the registers is supposed to (I think) indicate how much data is getting moved.  I've looked through my book and can't seem to sort how this is determined.

Is there a general way of figuring this out?

Comment: So basically you're asking what "word", "double word" and "quad" means? Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/621657/how-many-bits-is-a-word-and-is-that-constant-over-different-architectures answer your question?

Comment: Nah, it's more how to tell given "%eax" and (%rsp) whether a byte, word, double word, or quad is meant...know what I mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If one operand of `mov` is a register, then the size is implied: `AL` is one byte, `AX` two, `EAX` four and `RAX` eight. If one operand is a memory location and the other an immediate value, *you* have to specify the desired size:

```
mov  BYTE PTR [RAX], 1    ;  *(uint8_t *)(rax) = 1
mov  WORD PTR [RAX], 1    ; *(uint16_t *)(rax) = 1
mov DWORD PTR [RAX], 1    ; *(uint32_t *)(rax) = 1
mov QWORD PTR [RAX], 1    ; *(uint64_t *)(rax) = 1
```

The above is Intel syntax as used by the architecture manual. In AT&T syntax, the first line would be `movb $1, (%rax)`; AT&T syntax uses suffixed instructions like `movb`, `movw`, `movd` and `movq` to indicate operand widths.

Comment: ah ok, so my book says "the original 8086 had eight 16-bit registers %ax through %bp...with 32-bit registers, they're labeled %eax through %ebp...this seems dumb but how are they enumerating these registers?  e.g. %ax, ..., %bp  What're the 6 filling in the ellipsis?

Comment: @bclayman: Read the architecture manual? The general purpose registers are AX, BX, CX, DX, SI, DI, SP and BP. x86-64 adds another 8, named R08-R15, and it uses R00-R07 as aliases for the original 8.

Answer (score 5):

AT&T assembler is not ambiguous, so it must match the operands, even if the operands(registers) contain enough size information.

%eax is a 32-bit register (just like %al is 8-bit, %ax is 16-bit and %rax is 64-bit).

While %rsp in (%rsp) is 64-bit, the expression (%rsp) is a move to the memory location held in %rsp, and as such has no register size associated to it.

So the mov(e) is 32-bit, and the suffix is l.